# Is it worth registering for an innovations in medicine conference, being a CE student?

Tags: conference, computer-science, cv, medicine

I'm attending an "Innovations in medicine" conference but the registration fee is a bit high, I am a computer engineering student and the conference will have various technological topics.

Do you think that having the attendance certificate from the conference will be of any value in my CV, considering the fact that there are some chances I might work in medical technology in the future?

Comment: By *having the papers from the conference*, do you mean to have the CD of the papers of the conference?

Comment: I really don't know what they give you, there's some document that proves you attended, plus some "bells and whistles", but at any rate I mean, is it worth getting the proof of your attending it? That's what I'm interested in actually, just proving I was there.

Comment: I edited your question to better imply what you mean.

Comment: Are you attending it or just thinking of going?

Comment: Attending, but it was worth the sightseeing anyway so you get the picture.
Thanks for the edit, looks better and is definitely more to the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Full disclosure: I originally planned to go to medical school, but things happened and I received an MS in CS instead.*

The question on whether you should attend weighs heavily on something you haven't clearly specified: **how serious is medicine for you?**

If you're just "Oh, I might do something medically related and want to attend" feel free to attend. However, unless you're actually studying biology or other related medical topics, this conference will not provide you very much besides being a CV stuffer.

Both medicine and CS alone are full-time education paths. If you're learning 10 CS courses for 1 intro to biology course, then I would say medicine is not really an associated topic of study. I would say, at the very least, you should have enough credits to have a minor in Biology or some other medically related field to indicate an actual understanding of the medical field.

If you are super-interested in the topic of medicine and feel that "Yes, this is what I want to do," then this is a program you should attend. You will meet people, make connections, and possibly end up doing research with them. The conference is a source of opportunities. You have to back up that dedication with actually learning biology, chemistry, and physiology. Like any set of study, learning medicine is a commitment.

That being said, medicine and computer science together tends to be more towards the Bio-Medical Engineering field. Or Bioinformatics, both of which are graduate-level programs as well. Plenty of things in these fields, like robo-surgery or automated diagnosis, and all great research-friendly topics. Electronic medical records software and clinical trials software, however, medical knowledge is usually not required and can be provided by people trained in the medical field.

Comment: Bioinformatics are a path I'm considering seriously, and since it was mostly an engineering conference around medical technologies, I was interested. However it turns out that to get the papers would cost well over the minimum wage of a full time worker where I live, and I have more profitable plans for my savings, so there was no point in it. The answer was a great one, hopefully others with similar dilemmas will stumble upon it.